# Using multiple Wordpress sites in a Network (MultiSite)

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to share blogroll links between different Wordpress Multi Network sites? I would like to link all sites to eachother (about 15) in a Network widget/menu on the right. All are pretty much in same niche.

I would not mind being able to manage some content as a Users database and Blogroll links centrally, I have been unable to find out how to do this.

It seems unique tables were generated per site, which makes me doubt if this is possible.

How can I get pretty statistics per subdomain? I don't want to create 15 sites in Analytics or Piwik, if this is no necessary.

Any tips for running Wordpress in an Networked environment are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of (unfortunately) premium plugins that will do as you ask:

[Sitewide blogroll links](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/sitewide-blogroll-links)

is purely a blogroll that can be centrally published.  For something a bit more specific to the network, look into:

[WP Social Blogroll](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-reading-blogroll/)

That one takes a little bit of doing to configure it, but it does work in Network mode.

For stats, you don't have a lot of good choices.  I would tend to stick with Google Analytics, run a single master UA code and just use filters to shard off each of the network sites for reporting purposes.  Depending on how your network is configured, there is (again, unfortunately) another [premium plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/google-analytics-for-wordpress-mu-sitewide-and-single-blog-solution) that specifically supports WordPress Network mode.  If you are running it in sub-domains, that plugin should automatically track by sub-domain.